# regex not working as it should

Tags: regex

I'm trying to catch up on regex and I have made one as below;

```
^(.){1};(\d){4};(\d){8};[A,K]{1};(\d){7,8};(\d){8};[A-Z ]{1,};[ ,\d]{1};(\d){8};(\d){1};(\d){1}; $
```

and the sample is;

```
ä;1234;00126434;K;11821111;00000000;SOME TEXT ; 0;00000000;0;0;
```

As far as I've read

**.** is all chars, **\d** is digits, **{n}** and variations indicates **n** time and depending on variation, more repetitions.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: You might find http://www.debuggex.com/ useful.

Comment: wow,debuggex is heavenly

Comment: Did you **escape** your strings correctly? So your compilers doesn't turn `\d` into `d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions/observations:

- You can remove all `{1}`s, they don't do anything.
- `[A,K]` means "`A`, `,` or `K`". If you want to match any letter between `A` and `K`, use `[A-K]`.
- You should place the capturing group around the repetitions: `(\d{7,8})` captures a 7-8 digit number; `(\d){7,8}` will only capture the last digit.
- `[ ,\d]{1}` fails on your regex because there are two characters (space and `0`) at that point in the string.
- you might need to remove the space before the final `$`, unless there actually is a space in your string after the last semicolon.

Here's a version that matches (and captures each element in a separate group):

```
^(.);(\d{4});(\d{8});([A-K]);(\d{7,8});(\d{8});([A-Z ]+);([ ,\d]+);(\d{8});(\d);(\d); *$
```

See it [in action on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/rF4lW7).

Answer (score 2):

Please, **don't abuse regexps** for everything.

Your format is a CSV format, just **split at `;`** and the validate the individual parts properly. This is perfectly valid, usually similarly efficient, and easier to debug.

With regexp, make sure you properly escape (i.e. double escape!). In most programming languages, `\` is a reserved character in strings, and you will need to use `\\` to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^(.){1};(\d){4};(\d){8};[A-K]{1};(\d){7,8};(\d){8};[A-Z ]{1,};[ \d]{2};(\d){8};(\d){1};(\d){1};$
```

Here what was happening in your regex
`^(.){1};(\d){4};(\d){8};[A,K]{1};(\d){7,8};(\d){8};[A-Z ]{1,};[ ,\d]{1};(\d){8};(\d){1};(\d){1}; $`

- You have extra space before `$` at the end.
- To specify range use `-` and not comma, Your range should be `[A-K]`.
- In `[ ,\d]` range You have restricted it to 1 character `{1}` it should be `{2}` one for
  space and 1 for digit.

Additional: You don't need to specify `{1}` as it will match one preceding token by default

Comment: You missed starting `ä` character : here is edit http://www.rubular.com/r/NLtYbNlnjT

Answer (score 0):

If yours does not work, you can try this one :

```
^(.){1};(\d){4};(\d){8};[A,K]{1};(\d){7,8};(\d){8};[A-Z ]{1,};( \d){1};(\d){8};(\d){1};(\d){1};$
```

Comment: It matches on www.rubular.com and http://www.debuggex.com/ ... Maybe you paste a space character after...

Comment: look at the capturing groups http://www.rubular.com/r/Pa4BgYKtPi either remove them ore expand them so that they capture something valid

Comment: ok ! thank you ! I did not noticed that, I have one match more. Thx !